# Finding the laurent expansion of $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to  find the Laurent series for $\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ in the region $1 < |z| < 2$. This implies that $\frac{1}{|z|} < 1$, so noticing that $(z-1) = z(1 - \frac 1 z)$ I can rewrite the desired function as
$$\frac{z}{z(1- \frac 1 z)(z-2)} = \frac{1}{z-2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac 1 z}.$$

Now using the definition of the geometric series I rewrite it as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^k(z-2)}$$
Is this the right Laurent series, and if not, where did I go wrong? Please note I am trying to understand where I made a mistake, *not simply finding any solution*.

I've read a similar question at [Finding the Laurent series of $f(z)=1/((z-1)(z-2))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79012/finding-the-laurent-series-of-fz-1-z-1z-2) and one answer uses the fact that $\frac{|z|}2 < 1$, but I am not sure if my method is also valid.

Comment: This is not a Laurent series.

Comment: @Anne Bauval I thought we could use known Taylor series and combine them to make a Laurent series, e.g. wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) says: "one often pieces together the Laurent series by combining known Taylor expansions"

Comment: Hint: First decompose the rational function using partial fractions.

Comment: @SammyBlack I understand the partial fraction method, my question is more about why my method may not work (it gets a different result than the method with partial fractions)

Comment: I don’t see a result yet. The $(z-2)$ factor in the denominator of each term in the series means that this expression is not a Laurent series.

Comment: The series needs to look like $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n z^n$$ for some coefficients $\{\dots, a_{-2}, a_{-1}, a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots\}$.

Comment: Sometimes this expression is “folded” to allow for it to be indexed just in one direction, with two terms per index: $$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigl( a_n z^n + a_{-n} z^{-n} \bigr), $$ but this is just a difference of notation.

Comment: @SammyBlack I see - so mathematically, my approach works (i.e., no illegal math in the intermediate steps), it just doesn't get me to a Laurent series, which is why we would need partial fractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $1 < |z| < 2$,
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)} &=-\frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z-2}\\
&=-\frac{1}{z}\left[\frac{1}{1-(1/z)}\right]-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1-(z/2)}\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^n\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)}
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n+1}\\
&=-1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n}\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{n}\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Since $\dfrac 1{z-2}=-\dfrac 12\dfrac 1{1-\frac z2}=-\dfrac 12\sum \left(\dfrac z2\right)^n$ converges for $\lvert \dfrac z2\rvert \lt1$, or $\lvert z\rvert \lt 2$, we can do this.

Because $$\dfrac z{(z-1)(z-2)}= z\cdot \left(\dfrac 1{z-2}-\dfrac 1{z-1}\right),$$ we get

$$ -\sum z^{-n}-\dfrac z2\cdot \sum\left(\dfrac z2\right)^n=-\sum_{n\ge0}z^{-n}-\left(\dfrac z2\right)^{n+1},$$ which is in powers of $z$ on the annulus $1\lt\lvert z\rvert \lt2$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right Laurent series, and if not, where did I go wrong?

The condition $1<|z|<2$ itself is sufficient to tell that each term of the Laurent series expansion must contain either negative or non-negative power of $z$ because the annular region $r<|z-z_0|<R$ between two concentric circles has center $z_0$ ; which is also the center of series. In your case, it is $0$. The correct expansion will be obtained by using partial fractions as displayed in other answers.